# FPDF does not accept UFT8 on variables

Tags: php, fpdf

```
$pdf->text(102, 101, iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252',$geslachtsnaam_vertegenwoordiger), TRUE);
```

This is the function I am using to make FPDF accept letters like : `ä` and `é`.

It does work when I use it on normal text, but not on a variable.

It gives me : `x&aumlnder`

It works on static text but not on variable text which came from the database.

Can someone please help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please use tcpdf instead of FPDF.

Answer (score 0):

Are you [storing the text in the database as UTF-8](http://jonisalonen.com/2012/ultimate-guide-to-utf8-and-mysql/), and are you [getting the data from the database in UTF-8](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php)?